# I could not mount docker's file system to host's file system

Tags: docker

My docker image is running with below command successfully

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -t springboot/spring-boot-docker
```

but i want to want to mount docker file system to host's file system as below
it failed

```
docker run  -v /home/opt/springboot:/opt/springboot -p 8080:8080 -t springboot/spring-boot-docker
```

Error message is

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /opt/springboot/app.jar
```

My Host system is linux@AWS's ECS

My docker file is like below

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD springboot-1.0.jar /opt/springboot/app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/opt/springboot/app.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

Any hints or suggestions are more than welcome!

Comment: What do you mean "it failed"? Failed how exactly?

Comment: Why are you mounting that directory whenever your Dockerfile already copies in the file that you are trying to use from the mount?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to mount that directory to the host? Are there any files you want to access?

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you mount a directory from the host to a container, all contents of the container's directory get replaced by the contents of the host's directory.

In your case that means that the previously added file `/opt/springboot/app.jar` in the build phase, disappears because you practically overwrite the containing directory when you start the container. Your entry point needs that file, but it does not find it and exits with an error.

If you want to share files from the the container to the host, you have to use another mounted directory which is empty in the container and copy files inside the container after startup to that folder.

If you just want to copy files once, you can use the docker `cp` command:

```
docker cp <containerId>:/opt/springboot/filename /home/opt/springboot
```

Comment: No. the directory(/home/opt/springboot) is newly created on host for mounting

Comment: Yes, that might be. The important fact is: it is empty and when it gets mounted, all contents in container get replaced.